# What's the difference between calling time(() => {}) and time {}?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I'm using the metrics-scala library, and can't understand why the two calls below behave completely differently

```
// method 1
writeTimer.time(() => {
  // expensive operation
})

// method 2
writeTimer.time {
  // expensive operation
}
```

In the method 1 case, the expensive operation is never called, whereas in method 2, it is.

`writeTimer` is an instance of [`com.yammer.metrics.Timer`](https://github.com/codahale/metrics/blob/master/metrics-scala_2.9.1/src/main/scala/com/yammer/metrics/scala/Timer.scala#L14), where the `time` method is declared as:

```
/**
 * Runs f, recording its duration, and returns the result of f.
 */
def time[A](f: => A): A
```

I just resolved a bug in my code where I had to use method 2 to get it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me like in the first case, you are timing the operation of *declaring a function* that computes the expensive operation, and in the second case you are actually timing the expensive operation itself.

Comment: OMG, that's brilliant... Thanks for spotting it!